# How to configure JuJu Charms to automatically recover from machine failure?

Tags: juju, maas

I have a charm that can only run 1 unit, that is working great. When I deploy this charm, a machine is created via MAAS, the unit for my charm is installed and it runs just fine.

What I want to do is if the machine dies, have JuJu create a new machine and then deploy the charm and unit again to recover from the hardware failure.

I've looked at JuJu HA for the controllers but it doesn't mention recovering of charms on machines. Also note, I can only run 1 instance of this charm and I just want to make sure 1 is always running.

Comment: Did you find out how? I am looking for the same answers.

Comment: David - you can't, believe or not there is no failover built into this system. You have to write a script/agent to monitor this and start new machines/charms etc when you have a problem.... seems like a huge miss.

Comment: I found out you can scale up and then back down. That sometimes fixes things.